# CefSharp.Wpfのlocaleを変更する

Tags: c#, wpf

CefSharp.Wpfを使用してWebページを表示するWPFアプリケーションを作成しています。
CefSharpのLocaleを日本語に変更しようとし、CefSettingsのLocaleやLocalesDirPathに下記のように設定していますが、デフォルトのen-USのまま変更できません。

```
CefSettings settings = new CefSettings();
settings.Locale = "ja-JP";
settings.LocalesDirPath = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "locales";
```

また、下記サイトを参考にOnBeforeResourceLoadでAccept-LanguageをHeaderに追加を試みましたが、追加後Headerの中身を確認しても、Accept-LanguageがHeaderに追加されていませんでした。

https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/231

```
public CefReturnValue OnBeforeResourceLoad(IWebBrowser browser, IRequest request, bool isMainFrame)
{
    request.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "ja-JP");
    for(int i = 0; i < request.Headers.Count; i++)
    {
        // Accept-Languageで設定したものが入っていない
        Console.WriteLine(request.Headers[i].ToString());
    }
    return CefReturnValue.Continue;
}
```

CefSharp.WpfはVisual Studio 2015のNuGetからVersion 41を取得し使用しています。
OSはWindows 8.1 64bitです。
わかる方おりましたら、よろしくお願いいたします。

#### 追記

CefSharpの最新のCefSettings.hを確認したところ、

```
virtual property String^ AcceptLanguageList
```

が追加されていました。NuGetで取得したV41.0.0のCefSharpでは未実装なのでまだ動作確認できていませんが、おそらくこれを設定することでLocaleが変更できるのではと思います。

Answer (score 1):

自己解決しました。
最新のCefCharp 57.0.0では、CefSettingsではなくChromiumWebBrowserのインスタンスに対して下記コードを実行することで、言語を日本語に変更し、対象もWebサイトの表示を日本語にすることができました。

```
cefbrowser.BrowserSettings.AcceptLanguageList = "ja-JP";
```

Answer (score 0):

自分もやり方がわからず検索してたらここにたどり着きました

settings.AcceptLanguageList = "ja-JP"
settings.Locale = "ja"

上記で言語・コンテキストメニューを日本語にすることができました。